# How to count the levels of a tree in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, tree, eloquent

I would like to get the levels of a tree in laravel.
I have a tree of categories that goes to about three levels.

```
->parent category
  -->sub category
     -->child category
```

I would like to be able to know how many levels a parent category has beneath it. So in the example above the answer would be 2.

In my model I have the following relation defined:

```
public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
```

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Lets say Category `A` has 2 children called `B` and `C`, what if `C` has category `D` as a child, but `B` doesn't have a child, the outcome could in this case be 1 or 2. What exactly do you need this for?

Answer (score 0):

With relationships you can call them like they're a property. With that being said, you can get the same answer a couple ways.

**Property**

`$model->children->count();`

Doing it this way will run a select query which returns a collection, and then count them.

**Function**

`$model->children()->count();`

This will run one query, which counts the records.

Comment: If I understand OP correctly, he wants the amount of layers, not the amount of data in each layer